# Gradle sync taking too long to "actually start syncing"

Tags: windows-7, performance, sync, android-studio

I just installed android studio (3.4.2) on my PC (win 7), and I noticed that it really slow to do anything, mainly:

1. Slow start up : I noticed that the process already there when I clicked the shortcut in the start menu, but it just sit there (no CPU usage & low RAM usage) for a few minutes before starting to became active (starting to see increasing CPU & RAM usages)
2. Slow gradle sync : Same situation as above, for the first 20 minutes (sometimes longer) it just show "Gradle Sync : Build" and no CPU/RAM/Disk/Network activity in Task Manager.

I believe it's not my project files acting up because I can run android studio (3.4.1) normally on my laptop (win 10), and not my PC because other programs can run normally. FYI I am regularly maintaining my PC like CCleaning, defrag, SMART check, virus scan, malware scan, etc, and I have i3-4310 with 8GB RAM. So what can I do to fix this? I have tried re-install the Android Studio but no success.

Comment: I suggest you use an SSD instead of an HDD to speed up the Android Studio, as well as your Windows and other apps & games. Perhaps the delay before the sync is because of the slow network; Please, if your network has low speed, fix that.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not talking about "slow" as slow HDD vs SSD. And no, of course I've checked the network of all things. I've switched to Fedora in that PC and I didn't encounter the delay there. So I should've closed this question as this probably a problem within my Win 7 OS.

As for the cause, I haven't found any good leads because the logging didn't catch anything and I can't see what Gradle doing inside that delay duration.